# using setTimeout() and .call()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm a little stuck with trying to set a setTimeout to a function call that is made using the .call() method.

Basically, I've got an array of function references, am then stepping through them one by one and calling them with a certain setTimeout interval. The first function fires aok, but the second doesn't and I'm getting an error in the js console that I don't understand - the error is -

Uncaught TypeError: Object 73 has no method 'call'

The code:

```
        function scene1(){             
            alert("boo");
        }

        function scene2(){          
            alert("boo2");
        }            

        var arrAnimation = [];
        arrAnimation[0] = scene1;                   
        arrAnimation[1] = scene2;                 

        //step through the array
        for (var i = 0; i < arrAnimation.length; i++){
                setTimeout(arrAnimation[i],3000).call();                  
        }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `call` - all you need to do is pass the function to `setTimeout` and it will be run automatically:

```
setTimeout(arrAnimation[i],3000);
```

FYI on the error itself - `setTimeout` returns a number as a handle, which lets you cancel the timeout later if that is something you need.  Numbers don't have a `call` function.

Comment: Thanks Dennis - I don't know why I didn't even try that.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `.call` method in the wrong spot.  Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/JkLk2/